# What tools for created a dynamic prototype for TV, with simulation remote control?

Tags: interaction-design, prototype, software

I would like to know, what did you use as software for created a dynamic prototyping for TV.

I Know that possible with axure but it's more long and complicated.

what did you use for that ? 
A advice ?

Thank you !

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid product recommendations aren't on topic for this site. We focus on UX problems and their solutions. Discussion about tools is best done on other discussion forums, not a Q&A site.